# javascript scrolling menu with scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

Looking for an easy to use vertical sidebar with the following conditions.

The sidebar follows you as you move down the page. 
The sidebar contains a scrollbar for extra long lists.

Any help would be great!

Cheers,
Ash

Comment: how is this todo with ruby-on-rails?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for jQuery scroll follow  ??

**http://code.google.com/p/jquery-scroll-follow/downloads/list**

Here's a page using the above plugin  **http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/sf-example-1.html**

Answer (score 0):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/ - set a fixed height and add overflow-y: scroll to the CSS for the element and you're there!